# Quotation Marks in ASP form breaking content

Tags: forms, email, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using a multipart/form-data filed to submit a picture, name, comment in asp, and now the comment section (a textarea) is breaking anytime someone enters a quotation mark.

I've tried replacing using

```
story = Replace(story, chr(34), "&#039;")
```

But that still cuts off the result. Even if I reference just the form request, it cuts off at the quotation:

```
Request.Form("csStory")
```

I'm not sure how to proceed!

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting that far.  Last time I checked `Request.Form` was not compatible with multipart/form-data entity body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that the form was not even passing the incorrect code to the submit page, but rather only the characters before the first quotation, so I settled on re-writing the form value with javascript before I submit:

```
formDOMObj.story.value.replace(/(['"])/g, "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape single quotes, just double them. So try

```
story = Replace(story, "'", "''")
```